# Apply parameters to a button in a <View>

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, button

Hi this is my first time posting something to get some help. I would like to apply for example some letter spacing and some other css things to my button, but I can't. I'm a begginer in coding so I would like to know how could I do this the best way, and concretly explained so I can understand :)

Here's my code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Bienvenue{"\n"}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Accéder"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Mon écoute')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  Button :{

    letterSpacing:2,
      

  }
})

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ 

      flex: 1, 
      alignItems: 'center', 
      marginBottom : 540, 
      justifyContent: 'center' }}>

      <Text>Quelle est votre humeur aujourd'hui?</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Mon écoute" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmAge.jpg)

Comment: React Native's Button component doesn't support styling other than color https://reactnative.dev/docs/button#color But you can create your own button using Pressable https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable or you can use a ui kit that gives a button like React Native UI Kitten, React Native Paper or NativeBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than. using a button try TouchableOpacity

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Mon écoute')}
style={{padding:5,alignItems:'center',justifycontent:'center'}}
  >
<Text style={{letterSpacing:0.5}} >"Hey"<Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and I will be able now to design my button

Comment: got it great :D if you think it helped, you can accept this as the correct answer . thanks :D